# Python - make a search and retrieve a set amount of images from a search engine

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to get images from a search engine, to run some automated tests without the need to go online and pick them by hand.

I found an old example from 5 years ago (`ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images`), which sadly does not work anymore. What is the current method to do so in Python3? Ideally I would like to be able to pass a string with the search name, and retrieve a set amount of images, at full size.

I don't really mind which search engine is used; I just want to be sure that it is supported for the time being. Also I would like to avoid Selenium; I am planning to run this without any UI nor using the browser, all from terminal.

Comment: Just a note, you can use Selenium without any UI using a headless browser.

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of [pixabay](https://pixabay.com/api/docs/)? There is a [nice python wrapper](https://github.com/faraco/python-pixabay) for working with it as well.

Comment: Thanks, but this involve using a specific source for the images; while I would like to not have ties to a specific site or API.

Comment: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/10/12/scraping-images-with-python-and-scrapy/ here's a good example that doesn't involve a specific API.

Comment: Interesting one, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found a pretty good solution using BeautifulSoup.

It does not work on Google, since I get 403, but when faking the header in the request, is possible to get sometimes, data. I will have to experiment with different other sites.

So far the workflow is to search in the browser so I can get the url to pass to beautifulsoup. Once I get the url in code, I replaced the query part with a variable, so I can pass it programmatically.
Then I parse the output of beautifulsoup to extract the links to the images, and retrieve them using `requests`.

I wish there was a public API to get also parameters like picture size and such, but I found nothing that works currently.